# Error: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by even disabling only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, jasperserver, mysql-8.0

Jasperserver 6.4.3 error with mysql 8.

I have disabled only_full_group_by but again getting this error.

Please Help me to fix it.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'TEST_DB.TEST_INFO.USER_NAME'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:312)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: *Error: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by even disabling only_full_group_by* If you set `only_full_group_by` explicitly to OFF but receive the error message nevertheless then your query is executed in another connection (maybe you use connections pool or an application reconnects) - session setting acts in one connection only.

Comment: Recommendation - rewrite your query. As a palliative you may use ANY_VALUE() function (i.e. not `SELECT column, ...` but `SELECT ANY_VALUE(column), ...`).

Comment: @Akina (query is executed in another connection) how do i find connection details?

Comment: I don't know how this is implemented in Java. In MySQL there exists [CONNECTION_ID() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id). And [SHOW PROCESSLIST Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-processlist.html).